# Geom_point and geom_line on same line within facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-point

I am back trying to build on a figure I [asked about here yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249950/free-axis-along-particular-facets-in-facet-grid-ggplot/75250195?noredirect=1#comment132788181_75250195). Instead of a bar plot, however, I'm trying to see if I can use `geom_point()` to get the "Skipped" and "Attended" values together on one line within each facet, similar to the picture I've attached here.

With the current code (below), I can connect them but they are still jittered or positioned next to each other instead of overlayed on the same line.

I'm trying to do this in the context of stefan's answer to my question yesterday using `patchwork`, but to make things simpler here I've only provided the `ggplot()` portion of code below.

```
ggplot(dtest, aes(x = var2, y = avg2, color = var2)) +
  geom_point(size = 3,
               shape = 19) +
  geom_line(aes(group = outcome_type)) +
  facet_grid(wave ~ outcome_type) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Attended" = "blue",
                                "Skipped" = "green")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

```
structure(list(outcome_type = c("CT", "CT", "CT", "CI", "CI", 
"CI", "CE", "CE", "CE", "FZ", "FZ", "MZ", "MZ", "PSS", "PSS", 
"CSS", "CSS", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CI", "CI", "CI", "CE", "CE", 
"CE", "FZ", "FZ", "MZ", "MZ", "PSS", "PSS", "CSS", "CSS"), wave = c("Wave 1", 
"Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 2", 
"Wave 3", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 3", 
"Wave 1", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 2", 
"Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 2", "Wave 3", "Wave 2", 
"Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 3", "Wave 1", "Wave 3"), var2 = c("Skipped", 
"Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", 
"Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", 
"Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Skipped", "Attended", "Attended", 
"Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", 
"Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", "Attended", 
"Attended", "Attended", "Attended"), avg2 = c(30.21, 20.88, 25.43, 
7.68, 8.26, 7.89, 11.15, 8, 5.99, 1.64, 0.43, 0.6, 0.77, 0.01, 
-0.09, -0.2, -0.01, 24.01, 19.98, 29.04, 9.82, 12.41, 12.99, 
14.35, 11.01, 10, 2.36, 2.3, 1.51, 0.91, -0.23, -0.35, -0.17, 
-0.14), outcome_type2 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C", 
"Z", "SS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -34L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(outcome_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), wave = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), var2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), avg2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), outcome_type2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this by setting the numeric value as x-axis like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dtest, aes(x = avg2, y = outcome_type, color = var2)) +
  geom_point(size = 3,
             shape = 19) +
  geom_line(aes(group = outcome_type)) +
  #facet_grid(wave ~ outcome_type) +
  facet_wrap(~wave) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Attended" = "blue",
                                "Skipped" = "green")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(#axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! The main problem with this (and why I set them all up as separate facets originally) is that the avg2 range is so different for different groups, so when you combine them under one axis like this the "SS" and "Z" get really swamped.

Comment: Hi @a_todd12, you could try add `scales = "free"` to your `facet`?